# Setting up automatic crash dump generation on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, unmanaged, managed, crash-dumps

I've been looking around SO, but didn't find the definitive answer. I want to set up automatic crash dump generation on a production machine so that whenever a crash or hang happens, the dump will be saved to the disk without user's intervention.

I'd like to have a single solution that would handle both managed and unmanaged code on Windows XP (32bit) and Windows 7 (32bit) with minimum additional dependencies.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unmanaged code, you could wrap each thread with a [structured exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and call [GetExceptionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679357%28VS.85%29.aspx) in your filter expression to get a pointer to the `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` structure. Then call [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360%28VS.85%29.aspx) and remember to archive the PDB files from your build.

If you can install other tools on the production machine there is a comparison table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539117%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).